# Can you identify this font

Tags: font-identification

[image]Looking for help identifying this sans serif font. I tried WhatTheFont but no luck. Thanks.[image]

Comment: It's almost impossible to identify a font from a single letter. Do you have a sample with more letters available? Maybe also mention the context, where you saw it, where you found it, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the image update, but where did you find this? Where is it from? Are you sure it's a font?  Not all text is a font.

Answer (score 2):

Don't recognize it, but context would be helpful. Seems to be sort of glitchy/experimental/techno-blackletter with the perfectly rectangular top and curved lower part. Has a hint of some of the German Künstlerschrift types from the end of the nineteenth century that tried to blend calligraphy with type, and later types like Catull and Jim Rimmer's designs. A few Swiss Typefaces fonts use similar tricks, although they aren't so rooted in blackletter.

Source? If it's a pdf or a website disassembly tools could identify it.

**Update:** Now we can see more characters, the serifs don't seem to naturally grow out of the letters, there are some weird proportions on the H especially. The 'c' is a much better design concept than the others. So this could be an amateur design.

Comment: Yes the H is modified so it's a bit wonky, but the other characters are great. Pretty sure I've seen it before so it's not a custom wordmark. Also, my question was wrong since this is a serif font (flared serif?).

Comment: I bet there is a C in the name of the typeface. That C is so nice they would want to draw attention to it.

Comment: Yes, this would normally be called an incised or glyphic typeface with the small serifs. Ayer, Canela, Albertus and Harbour by Gareth Hague/Alias are typefaces in this style. The other weird proportion thing is the crossbar on the H, which is oddly low.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. The typeface is called Flecha from R-Typography.[image]